# SyntaxError: Unexpected token : MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Hello I seem to be getting a syntax error every time I try and run this command in MongoDB however I have absolutely know idea why:

```
db.inventory.find(); { "_id": ObjectId(".."), "title" : "A new car"};
```

I first ran this command and that went through smoothly as you can see by the WriteResult:

```
meteor:PRIMARY> db.inventory.insert({title: "A new car"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

However when I try and run the first command I am just left with this error now:

```
2015-11-28T16:02:04.255+0000 SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Any idea why this might be happening as I have no idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
db.inventory.find({ "_id": ObjectId(".."), "title" : "A new car"});
```

Comment: Tried this and now I get this error: Error: invalid object id: length

Comment: You'll see that message if your ObjectId has the wrong length.  It should be 24 characters long.  Here's a discussion about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/mongodb-user/Dr-3SxT_bl4/43rQMT8LxTcJ